# CMake: Is it possible to run the install step of make "automatically" when I compile via make?

Tags: cmake, makefile

Using cmake version 3.23.1, make: GNU Make 3.82.

I'd like my `project-targets.cmake` file (generated during the install step) to be created after the `make` step, but presently I have to run `make` then `make install` to generate these.    Is it possible to default to `make install` when I type `make` (without using an alias)?  i.e., `cmake ..; make -j8`, which would compile the codes, and perform the installation step.

I've tried adding custom cmake targets:

```
add_custom_target(default COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} install)
```

and

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build . --target install)
```

Seems like I'm missing something relatively simple.

This is about `cmake` behavior around the `Makefile` it generates, not about `make` in general.

Comment: "I'd like my "project-targets.cmake" file (generated during the install step)... " - If you are about the file generated with `isntall(EXPORT)`, then given file is generated during the **configuration** step, at the very end of it. So it is accessible during the building the project.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with makefiles: this is a cmake question.  Please remove the `makefile` tag.